# Merging all csvs in a folder and adding a new column with filename of original file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to merge all the csv files in a folder into one large csv file. I also need to add a new column to this merged csv that shows the original file that each row came from. This is the code I have so far:

```
import csv
import glob


read_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

source = []

with open("combined.files.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        source.append(f)
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
```

I know I have to somehow repeat each f for as many rows as are in each csv and then append that as a new column to the .write command, but I am not sure how to do this. Thank you everyone!

Comment: do you know for a fact that all your source files have the same column headings?

Comment: @PyNEwbie: yeah, they all have the same columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the filename as the final column, you don't need to parse the csv at all. Just read them line by line, add filename and write. And don't open in binary mode!

```
import glob
import os

out_filename = "combined.files.csv"
if os.path.exists(out_filename):
    os.remove(out_filename)

read_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
with open(out_filename, "w") as outfile:
    for filename in read_files:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write('{},{}\n'.format(line.strip(), filename))
```

If your csv's have a common header line, pick one to write to the outfile and supress the rest

```
import os
import glob

want_header = True
out_filename = "combined.files.csv"

if os.path.exists(out_filename):
    os.remove(out_filename)

read_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

with open(out_filename, "w") as outfile:
    for filename in read_files:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            if want_header:
                outfile.write('{},Filename\n'.format(next(infile).strip()))
                want_header = False
            else:
                next(infile)
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write('{},{}\n'.format(line.strip(), filename))
```

Comment: Maybe add `filename` as last column name when adding the header.

Comment: @tdelaney: Thanks for the help on this, but for some reason, your code starts writing a gigantic csv (+2gb) based on csv files that combined are only 10mb. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Silly mistake. Since we opened "combined.files.csv" in the same directory as the input csvs, `glob` finds it and and tries to add its contents to itself. I should have stuck to your example where we glob before creating the output csv. I'll update.

Comment: @tdelaney I thought that might be it. Thanks again for your help on this!

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the output again, the filename is being appended to each linebreak, not after the text block. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the row was `col1,col2,col3\n` it should become `col1,col2,col3,somefile.csv\n`.

Comment: How could this solution be modified to conditionally limit which rows are read in? For example, only lines from each csv file where the third column's value is "something". I tried adding`if line[2] == 'something':` above the `for line in infile:` statement. If appropriate I can make a new post for this question.